# String ComparisonL: 'TITLE' == 'TITLE' returns False, but 'TITLE' in 'TITLE' returns True

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, equality

I'm wondering about this behavior of python,
i have the following function:

```
def create_trigger(trig_type,arg1, arg2=None):
        """
        Assumes:
             trig_type: str which is either TITLE​, DESCRIPTION​, AFTER​, BEFORE​, NOT​, AND​, OR​
        Returns:
             correspoding trigger object
        """
        if trig_type == 'TITLE​':
            print('>>entering',trig_type,'trigger')
            return TitleTrigger(arg1)
        elif trig_type ==  'DESCRIPTION​':
            print('>>entering',trig_type,'trigger')
            return DescriptionTrigger(arg1)
        elif trig_type ==  'AFTER​':
            print('>>entering',trig_type,'trigger')
            return AfterTrigger(arg1)
        elif trig_type ==  'BEFORE​':
            print('>>entering',trig_type,'trigger')
            return BeforeTrigger(arg1)
        elif trig_type ==  'NOT​':
            print('>>entering',trig_type,'trigger')
            return NotTrigger(arg1)
        elif trig_type ==  'AND​':
            print('>>entering',trig_type,'trigger')
            return AndTrigger(arg1, arg2)
        elif trig_type ==  'OR':
            print('>>entering',trig_type,'trigger')
            return OrTrigger(arg1, arg2)
```

in which when `trig_type='TITLE'` the `==` operator returns `False`, also when I use `str.__eq__()`. but when I use `trig_type in 'TITLE'` it returns `True`.
What is causing this behavior? what is the best practice in this case

edit:

below is a minimal reproducible example

```
def read_trigger_config():
    """
    filename: the name of a trigger configuration file

    Returns: a list of trigger objects specified by the trigger configuration
        file.
    """
    class TitleTrigger(object):
        """
        mock class of TittleTrigger
        """
        def __init__(self, phrase):
            self.__phrase = phrase

    def create_trigger(trig_type,arg1, arg2=None):
        """
        Assumes:
             trig_type: str which is either TITLE​, DESCRIPTION​, AFTER​, BEFORE​, NOT​, AND​, OR​
        Returns:
             correspoding trigger object
        """
        
        print('checking if',trig_type,'== TITLE', trig_type == 'TITLE​')
        if trig_type == 'TITLE​':
            return TitleTrigger(arg1)
            
    lines = [['t1', 'TITLE', 'election']]
    triggers_dict = {}

    print(lines)
    for line in lines:
        if line[0] != 'ADD':
            if not line[1] in ('NOT', 'AND', 'OR'):
                triggers_dict[line[0]] = create_trigger(line[1], line[2])
            else:

                triggers_dict[line[0]]=create_trigger(line[1], triggers_dict[line[2]], triggers_dict[line[3]])
    print(triggers_dict)

read_trigger_config()
```

Comment: This is explained in Python's documentation. Is there a reason you didn't check there first?

Comment: I've read Language Reference 6. Expressions, but failed to understand what is the best practice when comparing strings

Comment: Show us you call the function.

Comment: Obviously `trig_type` doesn't contain what you think it contains. It might be `'TITLE '` or `'TITLE\n'` or some other value. Do `print(repr(trig_type))` and check the result.

Comment: @Matthias `print(repr(trig_type))` resulted in `'TITLE'`
@KlausD. I edited the calling function to the OP

Comment: `print([ord(x) for x in trig_type])`, then.

Comment: Can you make this into a [mre] -- code we can run ourselves with no changes whatsoever to see the problem, with everything unrelated or irrelevant removed? (Taking out file I/O and instead hardcoding data values that cause the problem in the code itself will do a lot of good towards making the code self-contained).

Comment: ...similarly, if you aren't actually asking about all your code iterating over the lines in `trigger_file`, try to take that code out; if you can still produce the problem without it, you know it wasn't the problem; if you can't, you can focus your question on only that code.

Comment: You've got a zero-width space in `'TITLE​'`.

Comment: (And in every other string you're comparing `trig_type` against.)